# Scalatest custom matchers for 'should contain'

Tags: scala, scalatest

This is a situation I have encountered frequently, but I have not been able to find a solution yet.

Suppose you have a list of persons and you just want to verify the person names.
This works:

```
persons.map(_.name) should contain theSameElementsAs(List("A","B"))
```

Instead, I would rather write this like

```
val toName: Person => String = _.name
persons should contain theSameElementsAs(List("A","B")) (after mapping toName)
```

because  this is how you would say this.

Sometimes however, you'd like to use a custom matcher which matches more than just one property of the object. How would it be possible to use

```
persons should contain(..)
```

syntax, but somehow be able to use a custom matcher?

Both these situations I could easily solve using JUnit or TestNG using Hamcrest matchers, but I have not found a way to do this with ScalaTest.

I have tried to use the 'after being' syntax from the Explicitly trait, but that's not possible since this takes a 'Normalization' which defines that the 'normalized' method uses the same type for the argument and return type. So it's not possible to change a Person to a String.
Also I have not succeeded yet in implementing an 'Explicitly' like trait because it does not like the Equality[.] type I return and/or it does not know anymore what the original list type was, so using '_.name' does not compile.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

You can manage something similar via the word `decided` and moderate abuse of the `Equality` trait. This is because the `Equality` trait's `areEqual` method takes a parameter of the generic type and one of type `Any`, so you can use that to compare `Person` with `String`, and `decided by` simply takes an `Equality` object which means you don't have to futz around with `Normality`.

```
import org.scalactic.Equality
import org.scalatest.{FreeSpec, Matchers}

final class Test extends FreeSpec with Matchers {

  case class Person(name: String)

  val people = List(Person("Alice"), Person("Eve"))

  val namesBeingEqual = MappingEquality[Person, String](p => p.name)

  "test should pass" in {
    (people should contain theSameElementsAs List("Alice", "Eve"))(
      decided by namesBeingEqual)
  }

  "test should fail" in {
    (people should contain theSameElementsAs List("Alice", "Bob"))(
      decided by namesBeingEqual)
  }

  case class MappingEquality[S, T](map: S => T) extends Equality[S] {

    override def areEqual(s: S, b: Any): Boolean = b match {
      case t: T => map(s) == t
      case _    => false
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure I'd say this is a good idea since it doesn't exactly behave in the way one would expect anything called `Equality` to behave, but it works.

You can even get the `beingMapped` syntax you suggest by adding it to `after` via implicit conversion:

```
  implicit class AfterExtensions(aft: TheAfterWord) {
    def beingMapped[S, T](map: S => T): Equality[S] = MappingEquality(map)
    }
  }
```

I did try getting it work with `after` via the `Uniformity` trait, which has similar methods involving `Any`, but ran into problems because the normalization is the wrong way around: I can create a `Uniformity[String]` object from your example, but not a `Uniformity[Person]` one. (The reason is that there's a `normalized` method returning the generic type which is used to construct the `Equality` object, meaning that in order to compare strings with strings the left-side input must be a string.) This means that the only way to write it is with the expected vs actual values in the opposite order from normally:

```
"test should succeed" in {
    val mappedToName = MappingUniformity[Person, String](person => person.name)
    (List("Alice", "Eve") should contain theSameElementsAs people)(
      after being mappedToName)
  }

  case class MappingUniformity[S, T](map: S => T) extends Uniformity[T] {

    override def normalizedOrSame(b: Any): Any = b match {
      case s: S => map(s)
      case t: T => t
    }

    override def normalizedCanHandle(b: Any): Boolean =
      b.isInstanceOf[S] || b.isInstanceOf[T]

    override def normalized(s: T): T = s
  }
```

Definitely not how you'd usually want to write this.

Answer (score 0):

use [inspectors](https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.10/org/scalatest/Inspectors.html)

```
 forAll (xs) { x => x should be < 3 }
```